# Clear cache onDestroy() at MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I tried to clear cache `onDestroy()` event as follow. But it doesn't work and cache size is still increasing. Where is it wrong? Thanks

```
 @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
           super.onDestroy();
           try {
              trimCache(this);
           } catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }

        public static void trimCache(Context context) {
           try {
              File dir = context.getCacheDir();
              if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
                 deleteDir(dir);
              }
           } catch (Exception e) {
              // TODO: handle exception
           }
        }

        public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
           if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
              String[] children = dir.list();
              for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                 boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                 if (!success) {
                    return false;
                 }
              }
           }

           // The directory is now empty so delete it
           return dir.delete();
        }
```

Comment: Don't you need to delete each file your directory/subdir before deleting the directory?

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Where does it stop working as expected? Is `getCacheDir()` returning the expected filename?

Comment: (By the way, you're checking for a `null` value in `dir` before checking whether it's a directory/looping through its children, but not before calling `dir.delete`, so a `null` value will still cause a NPE.)

Comment: Thanks I put if (dir != null) before ret = dir.delete();

Answer (score 0):

Try to check **null** result of **dir.list()**. Probably some dir has no contents and you catch **NPE** at **children.length**

Comment: You mean if(children != null) to put before for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) for loop?

Comment: yes. And do not use *catch (Exception e)*. Especially with empty body!

Comment: But I think it has no relationship with cache size increment. Size is still increasing.